# Equivalent to cmd 'call' command?

Tags: powershell

When creating a cmd/batch script (e.g. `parent.bat`), it is possible to use the 'call' command to call another batch file (e.g. `child.bat`). The instructions found in the `child.bat` would run as part of the `parent.bat`.
Any variables that the `parent.bat` would use, the `child.bat` could use and vice versa.

Is it possible to pass through variables from the `parent.ps1` to a `child.ps1` and vice versa in PowerShell?

Comment: Read up on 'dot sourcing' in powershell, I think that's what you're after

Comment: Thank you. Dot sourcing was what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell scripts called inside another script will have access to the parent script's variables, but any modifications will be lost as they are saved in the local-scope (read more [about scopes here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)).

Parent.ps1

```
$MyVariable = "Foo"
Write-Host "PARENT BEFORE: MyVariable: $MyVariable"
& "$PSScriptRoot\Child.ps1"
Write-Host "PARENT AFTER: MyVariable: $MyVariable"
```

Child.ps1

```
Write-Host "CHILD BEFORE: MyVariable: $MyVariable"
$MyVariable = "Bar"
Write-Host "CHILD AFTER: MyVariable: $MyVariable"
```

Output:

```
PS > .\Parent.ps1
PARENT BEFORE: MyVariable: Foo
CHILD BEFORE: MyVariable: Foo
CHILD AFTER: MyVariable: Bar
PARENT AFTER: MyVariable: Foo
```

If you use dot-sourcing (`.`) to Call the child-script, it will run in the Scope of the parent script, which will make variable modifications in the child script visible for the parent. Ex:

Parent.ps1

```
$MyVariable = "Foo"
Write-Host "PARENT BEFORE: MyVariable: $MyVariable"
. "$PSScriptRoot\Child.ps1"
Write-Host "PARENT AFTER: MyVariable: $MyVariable"
```

Output:

```
PARENT BEFORE: MyVariable: Foo
CHILD BEFORE: MyVariable: Foo
CHILD AFTER: MyVariable: Bar
PARENT AFTER: MyVariable: Bar
```